# How to add distinct to filter expression in Defined Selector in Openbravo?

Tags: hql, openbravo

The filter expression which I am using now is,

```
"e.contract= '" +OB.getParameters().get('subscriptionId') + "'"
```

Here, e is the current table which is populated in 'Table' , and contract is the column there (In the POJO class) which stores the value of subscriptionId.

The issue is the attribute in the next level Defined Selector Field ,which I display a certain column exColumn has many rows [selected from the above expression] with same value.

Here , I intend to add a distinct in the filter expression or in the HQL [which doesn't seem to be filtering at run time] or in the Defined Selector Field, so that we don't display repeated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add `distinct` in a Filter Expression, which is used to restrict the results of the datasource.

You have 2 different options:

1. Define the selector based on a *Custom Query* and write there the HQL to retrieve the values. In this query you can have the `distinct`. As example you can check *Business Partner not filtered by default by customer/vendor* selector which is implemented in this way.
2. Base your selector on a Table from a view:

   - Create a database view with the base SQL query you need including the `distinct`.
   - Register it as an Application Dictionary *Table*
   - Base your selector on it

Comment: I had success with Option-1.